# Can anyone compute this conditional expected value?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, expected-value

The random sample we have is $X_1,\cdots, X_n$ iid with exponential distribution with parameter ${1}$. I want to find the conditional distribution of $X_1$ with respect to $S=X_1+\cdots+X_n$. I know that the distribution of $S$ is the gamma with parameters $(n,1)$, but I don't know how to find the conditional distribution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: The conditional expected value is $\frac1n$ by symmetry.  Slightly more interesting is the conditional distribution, which is $\text{Beta}(1, n-1)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables and put $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. No matter the distribution of $X_1$, we have by definition of conditional expectation and linearity
$$
S_n = \mathbb E[S_n\mid S_n] = \sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb E[X_1\mid S_n] = n\mathbb E[X_1\mid S_n],
$$
and hence
$$
\mathbb E[X_1\mid S_n] = \frac 1n S_n.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $S_n = X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_n=X_1+Y_{n-1}$, where $X_1$ and $Y_{n-1}$ are independent, $Y_{n-1}\sim\Gamma_{n-1,1}$, we can write joint pdf of $X_1$ and $Y_{n-1}$ as
$$f_{X_1,Y_{n-1}}(x,y) = e^{-x} \frac{1}{(n-2)!}y^{n-2}e^{-y}, \quad x,y>0.$$

Now $S_n=X_1+Y_{n-1}$ and $X_1=X_1$ is a linear transform of the pair $(X_1, Y_{n-1})$. Inverse transform is $X_1=X_1$ and $Y_{n-1}=S_n-X_1$.

The joint pdf of $(X_1, Y_{n-1})$ can be transformed to the joint pdf of $(X_1,S_n)$ by
$$
f_{X_1,S_n}(u,v) = f_{X_1,X_1+Y_{n-1}}(u,v) = f_{X_1,Y_{n-1}}(x(u,v),\;y(u,v))\;|J| = f_{X_1,Y_{n-1}}(u,\;v-u)\;|J|
$$
where $J$ is a Jacobian of inverse transform: $x=u, y=v-u$

$$J=\begin{vmatrix}
        \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\
        \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial v} \\
        \end{vmatrix}
=\begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        -1 & 1 \\
        \end{vmatrix} = 1.
$$

Therefore,

$$
f_{X_1,S_n}(u,v) = f_{X_1,Y_{n-1}}(u,\;v-u) = e^{-u} \frac{1}{(n-2)!}(v-u)^{n-2}e^{-(v-u)}
$$
$$ = \frac{1}{(n-2)!}(v-u)^{n-2}e^{-v} \text{ for $0< u < v$}.
$$
Next consider conditional pdf:
$$
f_{X_1|S_n}(u|v) = \dfrac{f_{X_1,S_n}(u,v)}{f_{S_n}(v)} = \dfrac{\frac{1}{(n-2)!}(v-u)^{n-2}e^{-v}}{\frac{1}{(n-1)!}v^{n-1}e^{-v}} = (n-1)\left(1-\frac{u}{v}\right)^{n-2}\cdot \frac1v 
$$
for  $0<u<v$.
This conditional distribution is a scaled Beta distribution. Indeed, if $X$ is Beta distributed with parameters $(1,n-1)$, then $Z=vX$ has the above pdf. It can be also described as [Beta distribution with $4$ parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Four_parameters) $(1,n-1,0,v)$.

If you really search for conditional expectation instead of conditional distribution, this way is too complicated and you should follow the way of @Math1000.